# Other possible ways to integrate 2checkout payment gateway

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, 2checkout

Is there any way to implement the checkout process aside from the ones found on the 2checkout site?  I would like to have my own checkout page in my website and just pass the data to 2checkout instead of redirecting it to 2checkout's checkout page using the inline method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2Checkout is currently in the process of beta testing their new checkout API solution which allows you to create a token from the card details client side and then submit the token server side with an API call to create a new sale. It sounds like you would be a great candidate for [2Checkout's API beta program](http://go.2checkout.com/api-pilot). A ruby library and full documentation will be provided to you once you signup.

Comment: Thanks @Craig-2Checkout. I'll definitely check this out. But for now, I'm currently using the direct payment method of 2checkout, the one that is using the javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

I think `2checkout` sites ruby example has what you are looking for,

[see here](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries/ruby/tutorial/), or check out this [rubygem](https://github.com/craigchristenson/2checkout-ruby)

Comment: I checked this out. Unfortunately it redirects to 2checkout's checkout page. I was hoping if i can just pass the data from my own checkout page in my site.